# S3 path configuration and SQS Extended Client Library

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I want to save all messages that go in a particular SQS queue in the already created s3 bucket.

But I want to save those messages in certain directories for an easier search by date and time.

**S3Client** has `software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest`

Where I can determine bucket, path where the object is saved and some headers

```
PutObjectRequest objectRequest =
    PutObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .key(s3Path)
        .metadata(keyAndMetadata.getMetadata())
        .build();
```

After that `s3Client.putObject(objectRequest, body)` do the thing

Now, I want to configure s3 in a similar way using `ExtendedClientConfiguration`, but I can only see very simple input parameters

```
 ExtendedClientConfiguration extendedClientConfiguration =
      new ExtendedClientConfiguration()
          .withPayloadSupportEnabled(s3Client, bucketName, false)
          .withAlwaysThroughS3(true);
```

And after that, we create that extended Sqs client with no way to configure s3 more extensively

```
AmazonSQSExtendedClient amazonSQSExtendedClient = new AmazonSQSExtendedClient(sqsClient, extendedClientConfiguration);
```

I know that I could probably separately save all messages that go to SQS to s3, but I'd better configure all that on the client level. Does someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found out there's no way to configure s3 path on the client level. But back up to s3 wasn't created for that purpose, and saving to s3 probably should be handled differently. Deleting files from s3 as they disappear from SQS is the best option for using this library.